# what is the different of zh_CN.UTF-8 and en_US.UTF-8 in *nix locale setting?

Tags: unix, utf-8

When working on *nix system, I always set the locale as `en_US.UTF-8`, and then this can help me display the Chinese correctly on the stdout.

But I know that there is also zh_CN.UTF-8 for locale setting as well, so I want to know:
What the the different of them?
When should I use zh_CN.UTF-8 or en_US.UTF-8?

Answer (score 3):

Having zero knowledge about zh in itself, changing between the two locales you mentioned *may* change how certain characters are treated at a word boundary and how different programs produce output.

For example `LC_CTYPE=zh_CN.UTF-8` will most likely consider characters with accent marks as "being part of a word" whereas `LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8` might not consider those being part of a word.

Same goes for date and currency formats. As I'm pretty sure zh will have different date/currency format than us.

To give you a concrete example, here is what I get from date(1) with two different locales in a relatively recent Ubuntu GNU/Linux system:

```
user@devbook:~$ LC_TIME=fi_FI.UTF-8 date
to 16.1.2014 07.14.36 +0200
user@devbook:~$ LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8 date
Thu Jan 16 07:14:42 EET 2014
```

Comment: In your LC_TIME example, I tested on my machine and got the same output of date, which just like `Thu Jan 16 07:14:42 EET 2014`. Can you tell me why?

Comment: There are more than a few possibilities. What pops first into my mind is that maybe locale-files aren't generated for the target locale, but as said, there are many other ways of making this go not the way it did in the example. Knowing your operating system (unix is rather generic covering anything from various GNU/Linux distributions to commercial unixen) and version might help to determine what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/E26033/glmbx.html):

> A locale consists of a number of categories for which
>   country-dependent formatting or other specifications exist. A
>   program's locale defines its code sets, date and time formatting
>   conventions, monetary conventions, decimal formatting conventions, and
>   collation (sort) order.

If two locales both have UTF-8 in their names, they have the same encoding. Their difference resides in locale-dependent settings. For example, time format as @Sami Laine has already pointed out; monetary sign, in `zh_CN.UTF-8`, the money sign is `￥` while in `en_US.UTF-8`, the money sign is `$`.

## More complete list of differences

According to [here](https://community.hpe.com/t5/General/Difference-between-C-utf8-and-en-us-utf8-points/td-p/4418194), for a more complete difference between the two locales, run the follwoing script,

```
CATS="LC_CTYPE LC_COLLATE LC_MONETARY LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME LC_MESSAGES"
LANG=en_US.utf8 locale -k $CATS > en_US.utf8.out
LANG=zh_CN.utf8 locale -k $CATS > zh_CN.utf8.out

diff en_US.utf8.out zh_CN.utf8.out
```

The above script should give a more detailed difference between the two locales.