# Difference between UTF-8 and en_AU.UTF-8

Tags: utf-8

I have some text in UTF-8 and it still shows weird in text editor (text editor has UTF-8 encoding set). I know that for instance ISO8859-2 is one byte encoding compatible with ascii that has high 128 values specific for territority, so ppl from that territority can still use one byte encoding to show characters that are not part of ascii and doesn't need to use multibyte encoding like UTF-8. What purpose has that en_AU part of en_AU.UTF-8? Couldn't it be somehow the reason why i still see my text messed even if it is in UTF-8? I mean that some values should be mapped to different characters when the en_AU is used? As i understand UTF-8 it is not possible, but that is the last thing it can be the reason why the text is messed.

**output from locale command on linux**

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=cs_CZ.UTF-8
LC_TIME=cs_CZ.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=cs_CZ.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=cs_CZ.UTF-8
LC_NAME=cs_CZ.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=cs_CZ.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=cs_CZ.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=cs_CZ.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=cs_CZ.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: Where are you seeing "en_AU.UTF-8"?

Comment: @IMSoP: that was just example, i will add output from my locale on elementary os

Comment: Related post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21153485/what-is-the-different-of-zh-cn-utf-8-and-en-us-utf-8-in-nix-locale-setting/48493433#48493433).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In UNIX systems, locales are files on disk and they're encoded in a specific encoding. So you may have the same locale in different encodings, e.g. `en_AU.iso55891` and `en_AU.UTF-8`. This is not some variation of UTF-8, rather it's a variation of this specific locale file. If your locales are using the UTF-8 variant of the locale then anything that's using the locale system will output UTF-8 encoded values.

Comment: What is the difference between, say, `en_US.utf8` and `zh_CN.utf8`? I thought that the UTF-8 encoding is the same for all languages.

Comment: Yeah, again, those are the UTF-8 variants of two different locales. Same UTF-8, different locale.